# Write simple Fortran program (*.f90) and compile using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fortran

How can I write a simple Fortran program (*.f90) and compile it using Visual Studion 2008? I need step by step procedure.

Comment: Do you have Intel's Fortran compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you'll need some pre-processing step which will turn your Fortran code into something like C++, C#, or VB. Visual Studio doesn't have a Fortran compiler.

If you are using Intel's Fortran compiler with VS (as suggested in a comment), start [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-for-windows-build-intel-mkl-program-with-intel-fortran-in-microsoft-visual-studio/). It has a step-by-step guide as requested.

In addition, Intel run their own forums which may have the information you require (or should respond if you ask them a question). Click [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/) and scroll down to `Intel® Software Development Products`.

Comment: If he's using VS, my guess is he's also using Intel's Fotran compiler, since it comes with a VS shell (VS integration).

Comment: PGI's compiler also has VS integration :)